# Rewrite Rule: Subdirectory to Subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite from a subdirectory to a subdirectory.

Example, I have an application on http://example.com/level1/level2.

Now I want to be able to visit http://example.com/level1 and the application should be opened which is on http://example.com/level1/level2.

Im just trying to figure out the rewrite rule since 2 hours, but nothing seems to work.
Is this even possible, or is rewriting only possible from root directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your  `/level1/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /level1/


RewriteRule ^((?!level2/).*)$ level2/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3832347.htm this is pretty much what i want to do, but their code also doesn't work..